# BrowserRouter from react-router-dom doesn't render components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I tried to move BrowserRouter out of my component. My App looked like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <BrowserRouter>
             <main>
               <Menu />
               <Switch>
                 <Route exact path="/about" component = {About} />
                 <Route exact path="/admin" component = {BooksForm} />
                 <Route exact path="/cart" component = {Cart} />
                 <Route exact path="/" component = {BookList} />
               </Switch>
               <Footer />
             </main>
          </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

And everything was working fine. But when I pulled BrowserRouter up, so my index.js would look like this:

```
const renderApp = () => (
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
)

const root = document.getElementById('app')
render(renderApp(), root)
```

it stopped working. When I click on one of the links the url changes but there's no change in my app. It renders new componennt only if I reload the page. How can I make it work without placing router component in the same component as Switch?

Answer (score 1):

Tough to tell without looking at the rest of the code.  Are you using the proper react-router `<Link>`s?  I assume you don't have the `<BrowserRouter>` element in both components, can't imagine that nesting them would do any good.

I'm on an old version of react-router, so I'm seeing some of these examples for the first time, but it looks like you don't need the `exact` keyword on all of those `<Route>`s within `<Switch>` -- the switch guarantees that only one of them will math.

Comment: My problem was solved by switching to `<Link>` from `<a>`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Allright I've made it working again. Connect from redux was causing the problem and withRouter solved it